# Function failure - shell script converted from Bash to Korn

Tags: bash, ksh

I wrote a shell script that does data manipulation on a server running bash shell.

My script has a function which retrieves data inside ZIP files

```
function getCTLfile() {
  for i in ${Array[@]}; do 
    if [[ `echo ${i}|awk -F . '{print $NF}'` == "ctl" ]]; then 
      echo "${i}" 
    fi
  done
}
```

It works great but this machine hardware is faulty so our sysadmin requested that I port my code to another server running Korn shell.

When I run my script, it fails on my function!! Even if I type it from the command line.

```
$ function getCTLfile() {
-ksh: syntax error: `(' unexpected
```

Do I need to change my syntax anywhere? I did some research and it seems that everything should work.

Comment: code review: `if [[ "$i" == *.ctl ]]` is much clearer. You almost certainly want to quote `"${Array[@]}"`

Comment: `case $i in *.ctl) echo "$i";; esac` is a lot simpler, portable, and idiomatic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function declaration syntax in ksh either uses the `function` keyword *or* the parentheses, but not both. Leave out either the parentheses or the `function` keyword and it should work.

Comment: Damn. I did not pay attention to that little detail. Bingo. Accepted and voted up. I was going nuts! Thank you!!!

Comment: @Chris: By the way, please note there are differences in functionality between the two syntaxes in ksh93, specifically with the scope of declared (`typeset`) variables.